# Move Android Apps to SD card storage

Tags: sd-card

On Android phones / tablets that have an SD card, when you go to Apps, pick an App, then select Storage, some will have a "Change" option to allow you to seamlessly move that app over to the SD card, and some do not. Presumably this is something that some App authors write into their app, while other App authors are too lazy to do it (some Apps might have legitimate reasons to only be on internal storage, but e.g. pretty much every game has no legitimate reason not to allow the user to push their data over to external storage I'd say, and yet many do not have this option).

If I have a few hundred apps on my device, it is a chore to go through each one by one to find which can move, and which cannot (it's a very slow job, would take many hours).

Is there a way (possibly via an app to scan the installed apps, or, even better if there is some kind of console built into Android where we can run bash scripts or whatever programming tools we can use to manipulate the Android OS filesystem) to a) find out all Apps that are possible to move, and b) to initiate the move process for those apps from internal storage to SD card?

I currently have a Samsung Galaxy Tab s5e tablet, and since Android (finally) makes a pretty fine portable desktop (with a bluetooth keyboard and mouse), I really need/want to push as many Apps as possible to the SD card storage, it would be great to find ways to analyse / automate this process as above.

Comment: Check out [Apps Movable](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gmail.heagoo.sdcardmovable) and wait for someone posting the adb command